# VB.NET CALCULATES WRONG

Tags: vb.net, calculator

I have made a sodavending mashine, and it can show price, how much you pay, and it can give you money back, but for some reason, the program started to calculate wrong and it worked fine here the other day, and I haven't changed my code, so example I take a soda to 18 kroner, and i put 5 kr in the machine, then i press pay, and it by some reason says here are the money you have paid to much, and gives you -13 kr back, it did not do this here the other day, and as I said I haven't changed the code. Here are piece of code that annoys me: (the valuables is in danish)

```
'Her fortæller jeg om man har givet det beløb man skal
Private Sub ButtonBetal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonBetal.Click
    If TextBoxBeløb.Text = TextBoxPris.Text Then
        MsgBox("Værsgo")
    End If

    If TextBoxBeløb.Text < TextBoxPris.Text Then
        MsgBox("Ikke nok penge")
    End If

    If TextBoxBeløb.Text > TextBoxPris.Text Then
        MsgBox("Her er de overskyende penge og din sodavand :)")
    End If

    If TextBoxBeløb.Text > TextBoxPris.Text Then
        TextBoxPengeTilbage.Text = TextBoxBeløb.Text - TextBoxPris.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

If somebody can help I will be very greatfull

Comment: When you debug this, where *specifically* does it fail?  Why are you performing math on *text* values instead of *numeric* values?

Comment: please convert to integer before comparing

Comment: [Option Strict Off](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) claims yet another victim. This option should be **on**. Seriously.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be comparing string values, rather than numbers. Alphabetically, "13" is less than "5", which is why it's not working. You need to convert the text values into numbers, before carrying out the comparisons and calculations.

Something like: (hopefully this is correct, I'm a C# programmer, not VB)

```
Dim Beløb as Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBoxBeløb.Text)
Dim Pris as Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBoxPris.Text)

If Beløb = Pris Then
    MsgBox("Værsgo")
End If

If Beløb < Pris Then
    MsgBox("Ikke nok penge")
End If

If Beløb > Pris Then
    MsgBox("Her er de overskyende penge og din sodavand :)")
    TextBoxPengeTilbage.Text = Beløb - Pris
End If
```

Comment: I assumed Kr was the equivalent of a penny/cent, given the whole number examples in the OP's question. If that's not the case, then yes, they should be decimals.

Comment: Updated to use more appropriate decimals.

Comment: Hehe, no kr (kroner) is the danish currency. :)